# Fixing shift key on emacs for mac

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

I'm currently sshing from my mac to a CentOS box, where I run emacs.  For whatever reason, the `shift` key doesn't seem to work when issuing a keyboard sequence.  I suspect the wrong key code is being sent.

For example, I've remapped my help command to the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-?") 'help-command)
```

Executing this keyboard sequence in a typescript file reveals that it's invoking the `delete-backward-char` command, which is a compiled Lisp function from simple.el. (In order to even check what command the keyboard sequence was executing, I had to temporarily remap help to `C-o`.)

Similarly, I have the following key binding set up for typescript mode

```
(setq tss-popup-help-key "C-:")
```

Likewise, it looks like the `SHIFT` key hasn't registered because I get the following definition in the help manual when I reverse lookup the sequence:

```
; runs the command typescript-insert-and-indent, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `typescript.el'.

It is bound to ,, ;, ), (, }, {.

(typescript-insert-and-indent KEY)
```

In other words, emacs registers the colon as a semi-colon.

This is a recurring problem with keyboard sequences that require me to use a `SHIFT` key.   How do I get the `SHIFT` key to work properly when working on emacs through a mac?

For the record, when I use [Emacs for OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com/), the shift key works great.

Comment: This is mainly a limitation with terminal emulation (not with emacs, osx, or javascript (?)). Ctrl+Shift combinations are normally not handled by the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ctrl-Shift-key Beeps and Doesn't Send to Terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469049/ctrl-shift-key-beeps-and-doesnt-send-to-terminal)