# How to create custom escape sequence in mac terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

I don't understand how to create custom escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469049/ctrl-shift-key-beeps-and-doesnt-send-to-terminal)

My problem is that I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in emacs no-window mode under MacOS terminal. Currently I'm trying to bind this escape sequence to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> but I have troubles creating that escape sequence. Maybe there is a batter way to use complex (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>anykey</kbd>) bindings in MacOS terminal with emacs in no-window mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably assuming that <kbd>F12</kbd> is a character.  It is not.  Conventionally, function keys send a sequence of characters.

In Terminal's preferences screen, you can review (most of) the key bindings:

[image: keyboard preferences]

You can also add a key definition (after deciding what characters it ought to send), and associate the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> modifiers with that key:

[image: adding/editing a key]

For the sake of example, I used the sequence that xterm would send.  However, Terminal is not the same as xterm, and you may find other sequences more interesting.

Regarding the related question "What is the correct escape code for control/shift/s": there is no **correct** escape code because terminals (unless specially configured as illustrated above) do not distinguish between shifted- and unshifted-control characters.  To determine what is "correct", you will have to examine your emacs bindings to see what you should **send** to make it recognize the function you are asking about.

Comment: I want to send control+shift+s (emacs shortcut) as a sequence bind to control+shift+f12, not the sequence of ctrl+shift+f12. And I still have no idea how this sequence (ctrl+shift+s) should look like.

Comment: It's the same answer: you have to find what sequence of characters emacs expects, and bind the control/shift/s (in Terminal *Preferences*) to match that.

Comment: What is the correct escape code for control/shift/s because ^[[27;6;83~ doesn't work as I would expect.