# Proper way of creating complex escape code (escape sequence) in terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

I don't understand how to generate escape sequences eg. if:

> `^[[27;7;47~`
> maps to:
> `C-M-/`
>
> `^[[27;6;40~`
> maps to:
> `C-(`

so why this doesn't work as I would image:

> `^[[27;6;83~`
> doesn't map to:
> `C-S-s or control/shift/s`

while 83 is ASCII for uppercase 'S'.

What is the correct escape code for `control/shift/s` (lowercase)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequences that you're listing as examples look like xterm's programmed mode (the [modifyOtherKeys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys) resource, introduced in [2006](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_214)).  The resource setting corresponds to a [control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) which some emacs configurations know how to initialize.  Referring to the manual pages, that is **2**:

```
   2    enables this feature for keys including the exceptions
        listed.
```

Because it affects all of the modifiers (including <kbd>Shift</kbd>), just setting the corresponding resource is not very useful.

OSX Terminal doesn't support that control sequence (or anything like it).  If you want OSX Terminal to send those escape sequences, you'll have to setup your preferences as mentioned in *[How to create custom escape sequence in mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803063/how-to-create-custom-escape-sequence-in-mac-terminal)* (using xterm as a reference).  The same comment applies to other terminals which someone may suggest.

For the sake of example, here's a screenshot from one of my test programs showing <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>

[image: example of modifyOtherKeys]